# check Text is belongs to which categoty in a list in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, list, search

I am using a category Array namely `CategoryListSearch` which contains various categories like Mobile electronics, jewellery etc.

I am using a text box In that text box i am inserting a value like IPhone  so how can i match from the list that I phone belongs to category mobile.
 I am using this as a sample

```
if (txt != '') {
  $.each(CategoryListSearch, function(i, o) {
});
```

but don't know that how to compare text value from `CategoryListSearch`.

please help!

Comment: With almost 300 rep, you should know how to click the `<>` and create a [mcve]  - what is a CategoryListSearch?

Comment: Is `CategoryListSearch` an array or an object? We need examples of the content of this mysterious variable.

Comment: could you show us the snippet of CategoryListSearch ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(CategoryListSearch.indexOf(text) > -1) {
  //text is present
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this.use ternary operator`(?:)` inside loop.

```
if (txt != '') {
  $.each(CategoryListSearch, function(i, o) {
      var present = (o == txt) ? "Item present in list" : "No item in list";
      console.log(present);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your object is of tree-structure the following function first checks whether we are searching for the object itself. If not, then it is iterated and we search for the index/member.

```
getCategoryPath(obj, item) {
    if (obj === item) {
        return obj;
    }
    for (index in obj) {
        if ((typeof obj[index] === "undefined") || (obj[index] === null)) {
            //irrelevant leaf
        } else if (typeof obj[index] === "object") {
            var ret = getCategoryPath(obj[index], item);
            if (ret) {
                return ret.unshift(index);
            }
        } else if ((obj[index] === item) || (index === item)) {
            return [index];
        }
    }
}
```